# Вопрос по C или C++ (дизассемблер)

Tags: c++, c

Если функция (**FUN_001dd74c**) просто выполняется  и значение которая она возвращает ни к чему не присваивается это влияет на выполнение дальнейшего кода ?

```
int *local_50;
int Number_char;
**********
FUN_001dd74c(&local_50,Number_char,5);
**********
int ** FUN_001dd74c(int **param_1,int param_2,int param_3){
------Code_------
}
*******
```

P.s. Сам не работал раньше с C++ и C, и мне не понятно что означает  &local_50;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `&local_50` означает получение адреса в памяти переменной `local_50` в виде целого числа `int`. (Однако для хранения используется не тип `int`, а специальный тип – указатель).
2. Если с возвращаемым значением не производится никаких действий, в данном случае это не значит, что не произойдёт ничего. Причина проста: в функцию передаётся указатель на область памяти, следовательно, она может изменить информацию, хранящуюся в этой области.

Так как в данном случае `local_50` уже является указателем на число типа `int`, то `&local_50` возвратит значение типа `int**`, то есть указатель на указатель на `int` (указывает на область памяти, в которой хранится число, обозначающее область памяти, в которой лежит информация), который и принимает Ваша функция.